# Encoding illogical text output

Tags: encoding

I got this weird text output from a program and I can't figure out how to decode it. I'm not a coder and don't have much experience, but I did try a few online tools with no luck. all other text outputs worked fine except this one

"bAÐ¿Ñ-Ð…rbel" and "bAпїЅrbel"

Comment: From which program and how did you use it?

Comment: What it is the expected output? The text seems some UTF-8 text decoded as some windows code page.